# Smooth deletion of file

Tags: java

There are two methods of file deletion

```
1. file.delete()
2. file.deleteOnExit()
```

The file is not deleted and returns false and have tried both the cases. Now I need to find the actual reason why the deletion has not happened

How to find out the reason? Is any log needs to be enabled or trace out the issue?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure based on your description. But my guess is that you have a writer or reader (or a stream) open with the file.

Comment: Don't these methods return `void`?  How are they "returning false" in your code?

Comment: delete returns boolean and it is not void. however deleteOnExist is void

Comment: The [`File.delete()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#delete()) even provides a tip for a case like this: _"Note that the `Files` class defines the [`delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) method to throw an `IOException` when a file cannot be deleted. This is useful for error reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be deleted."_

Comment: Just in case it's **android**, `file.delete()` returned `false` without any error for me - since Android 11 you need to use `createDeleteRequest`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than two methods of deleting a file!

You can use the utility class [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
Files.delete(path);
```

will throw an IOException that will tell you the reason it failed.

Comment: @Kathir Because APIs evolve (and besides the `File.deleteOnExit()` is a special use-case)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's absolutely fine, however the methods are not deprecated and shows Files.delete to be used

Comment: `Files` is newer and works on a generalisation of `File`, **`Path`** that can be an URL, file in a zip directory, LDAP directory or whatever. And `deleteOnExit` serves as cleanup functionality, normally not to be used.

Comment: @Kathir Yes, the method is not deprecated because it is absolutely fine to be used, and there are no plans to remove it. Java itself generally only uses deprecation if things are considered a mistake and shouldn't be used, and/or might even get removed in a future version. Deprecating things just because there is a new or better API would annoy people to no end with things that are widely used because of all the deprecation warnings it would generate.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkRotteveel for your kind explanation and appreciate it